# How can I combine this Laravel Collection sort?

Tags: php, sorting, laravel, collections

This is what I currently have:

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

    $order = ['Land', 'Planeswalker', 'Creature', 'Instant', 'Sorcery', 'Enchantment', 'Artifact'];
    $landOrder = ['Basic', ''];

    $deck = $deck->sortBy(function($card) use ($landOrder) {
        foreach ($landOrder as $index => $supertypes) {
            if (str_contains($card->supertypes, $supertypes)) {
                return $index;
            }
        }
    })->values();

    $deck = $deck->sortBy(function($card) use ($order) {
        foreach ($order as $index => $type) {
            if (str_contains($card->types, $type)) {
                return $index;
            }
        }
    })->values();
```

Basically I'd like to sort by $order first and then tweak the order based on $landOrder.

Currently it sorts by whichever function was executed second. How can I make it so it sorts for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `sort` method instead of `sortBy`. The `sort` method uses the PHP `uasort` function, which gives you a little more control over the sorting functionality.

```
$deck->sort(function($a, $b) use ($order, $landOrder) {
    // get the order indexes for the two items
    $ai = array_search($a->types, $order);
    $bi = array_search($b->types, $order);

    // if the two items have the same order, drill down to the land order comparison
    if ($ai === $bi) {
        // get the land order indexes for the two items
        $aii = array_search($a->supertypes, $landOrder);
        $bii = array_search($b->supertypes, $landOrder);

        // order based on "natural order" comparison of land order indexes
        return strnatcmp($aii, $bii);
    }

    // order based on "natural order" comparison of order indexes
    return strnatcmp($ai, $bi);
})->values();
```

### Edit

You'll need to update the function to implement whatever logic is needed to get the correct index from the `$order` and `$landOrder` arrays. I just used `array_search()` as a quick and easy function, but this assumes that the value of the `types` and `supertypes` attributes would be exact matches to the entries in the arrays (i.e. 'Land' and 'Basic', not '["Land"]' and '["Basic"]').

Based on the logic from your question, and the format of the attributes from your comments, you're probably looking for something like this:

```
$deck->sort(function($a, $b) use ($order, $landOrder) {
    // get the order indexes for the two items
    $ai = null;
    $bi = null;
    foreach ($order as $index => $type) {
        if (str_contains($a->types, $type)) {
            $ai = $index;
        }
        if (str_contains($b->types, $type)) {
            $bi = $index;
        }
    }
    // if the type is not in the array, assign some type of value that will order like types together, but after all other proper types
    if (is_null($ai)) {
        $ai = count($order).$a->types;
    }
    if (is_null($bi)) {
        $bi = count($order).$b->types;
    }

    // if the two items have the same order, drill down to the land order comparison
    if ($ai === $bi) {
        // get the land order indexes for the two items
        $aii = null;
        $bii = null;
        foreach ($landOrder as $index => $supertype) {
            if (str_contains($a->supertypes, $supertype)) {
                $aii = $index;
            }
            if (str_contains($b->supertypes, $supertype)) {
                $bii = $index;
            }
        }
        // if the supertype is not in the array, assign some type of value that will order like supertypes together, but after all other proper supertypes
        if (is_null($aii)) {
            $aii = count($landOrder).$a->supertypes;
        }
        if (is_null($bii)) {
            $bii = count($landOrder).$b->supertypes;
        }

        // order based on "natural order" comparison of land order indexes
        return strnatcmp($aii, $bii);
    }

    // order based on "natural order" comparison of order indexes
    return strnatcmp($ai, $bi);
})->values();
```

Comment: I tried your answer and it does seem to be doing something but it's not quite right. I'm getting something like this: LandBasic1, LandBasic2, Creature1, Land3, Land4, Creature2, Planeswalker1, etc. The expected results are: LandBasic1, LandBasic2, Land3, Land4, Planeswalker1, Creature1, Creature2, leftovers, etc.

Comment: @rotaercz What exact code got you those results? And what do the objects `types` and `supertypes` fields look like?

Comment: types are just strings that contain values in the $order array. And supertypes are also strings that may or may not contain values in the $landOrder array.

Comment: Here's sample data: {
 "0" : {
  "types" : "[\"Land\"]",
  "supertypes" : "",
 },
 "1" : {
  "types" : "[\"Creature\"]",
  "supertypes" : "",
 },
 "2" : {
  "types" : "[\"Land\"]",
  "supertypes" : "",
 }
}